# How can I create a new user in all my single-sign-on sites when they register on any of them?

Tags: perl, wordpress, bbpress

I have an existing website written is Perl and have recently added a WordPress blog and BBPress forums. Each of the three systems has its own login mechanism.

To make this a little cleaner I have integrated WordPress and BBPress to enable single sign-on between the two systems which works great. I now want to take the next step and integrate things further so that when someone registers with our site our Perl scripts create a new WordPress user, a new BBPress user (if necessary) and logs the user into all three systems.

Also, when a user returns to the site, I'd like to log them back into all three systems. I'd appreciate any advice on how to best accomplish this.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a plan...which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I can't seem to find any good documentation on what needs to be done in my perl application for these 3 areas:

1) Setting up a new WordPress/BBPress user upon registration
2) Creating a valid WordPress/BBPress session upon login
3) Invalidating the WordPress/BBPress session upon logout

I was hoping someone who has worked much more closely with WordPress could help provide some insight.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering may be the answer, if you're feeling spunky. Set up an empty WordPress database and dump the SQL emitted by the app while going through the user registration flow. Rinse, repeat for any other WordPress flows that you'd like to *emulate* in your Perl app.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use LDAP or similar to unify the login, rather than create lots of accounts?

Comment: Looks like both BBPress and WordPress have LDAP plugins available (and openid too).

Comment: I'd prefer to do something a lot more light weight where my perl app could simple do that appropriate checks and create/destroy session cookies as necessary to enable registration and login/logout. Any other ideas besides using LDAP or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where perl stores it's data, if that user data it stores is file-based, then just read those files, and integrate perl users with wordpress users.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID implementation, perhaps? If you want some sort of federated login standard that's not LDAP. There's probably a plugin for that if there's one for LDAP.